# FormArray validator in Angular 2

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I have 4 formBuilder in Angular 2
- Personal information
- Adress information
- Financy information
- Partners information

for Personal, Adress and Financy I have a ready validator.

On partners, I have 2 fields : 'Name' and '% of company'.
On this part of form, I have a ArrayForm to add more than 1 partner, code below:

```
this.form4 = this.formBuilder.group({
            cadSocios: [{value: true, disabled: false}],

            socios: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.initSocios(),
            ])

        });


initSocios() {

        // initialize our address
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            nome: ['', Validators.required],
            participacao: ['', [Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[0-9]*")]]
        }, {validator: PartValidator.valPart()}));

    }
```

I have a custom validator to sum the percentage of the partners, that it needs to be 100%.(valPart()).

But, how can I access the values of array portentagem inside de function valPart()?

valPart() ->

```
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

export class PartValidator{
    static valPart(){

        return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {

        //CODE HERE


            return null;
        }//return

    }//valPart

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
unless calling valPart() in initSocios(), I call it in this.form4:

```
this.form4 = this.formBuilder.group({
            cadSocios: [{value: true, disabled: false}],

            socios: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.initAddress(),
            ])

        }, {validator: PartValidator.valPart()});
```

so, I get access the value in valPart():

```
   import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

export class PartValidator{
    static valPart(){

        return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {

           let parts = [];
           let soma = 0;

           if(group.get('cadSocios').value == true){

            parts.push(group.get('socios').value);

            parts[0].forEach((data) => {
        soma += parseInt(data.participacao);
        });


        if(soma !== 100){

                return {
                    valPart: true
                }

        }//if

           }

            return null;
        }//return

    }//valPart

};
```